# Efficient double for loop

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, processing-efficiency

What is the most efficient (or Pythonic way) to carry out a double for loop as in below (I know how to do this for list comprehension but not for a single object to be returned):

```
for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(0, 9):
        if self.get(i)[j] == "1":
            return (i, j)
```

Comment: That looks OK. If you _really_ need a for-loop inside another for-loop, you don't have any other way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> next(((i, j)
           for i in range(0, 9)
           for j in range(0, 9)
           if self.get(i)[j] == "1"), None)
```

This will return `None` if nothing is found.

See the documentation for [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next).

The first parameter is a generator. You need this if you supply `None` as the second parameter. Otherwise you can skip the extra parentheses. If you don't supply `None` though it will throw a [**`StopIteration`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) exception if nothing is found.