# more efficient way to search through geoJson in double for loop Python

Tags: python, for-loop, geojson, shapely

What is the most efficient (or Pythonic way) to search in double for loop through geoJson file?

I would like to find the Linestrings that starts or ends coordinates equals point coordinates. I mean, I need first iterate over point file then for loop over linestring file and in case coordinates are equal dump it into new geojson file.

You can see my code below:

```
for j, feature2 in enumerate(nav['features']):
    if feature2['properties']['gp'] in ('RTE', 'RTB', 'RTA'):
        for i, feature in enumerate(tra['features']):                
            segment = LineString(
                [Point(feature['geometry']["coordinates"][0]), Point(feature['geometry']["coordinates"][1])])
            if Point(poi) != Point(segment.coords[0]) and Point(poi) != Point(segment.coords[1]):
                continue
```

after that I do some calculations with these points and dump them to new file.

My point file contains ~ 10k and linestring file ~ 90k objects and now processing takes more than a day. 
I found [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976373/efficient-double-for-loop) but it seems to have no effect in my case

I will appreciate any ideas of how process this more elegant and efficient!